# Creating a FILE * stream that results in a string

Tags: c, string, file, stream, printf

I'm looking for a way to pass in a `FILE *` to some function so that the function can write to it with `fprintf`.  This is easy if I want the output to turn up in an actual file on disk, say.  But what I'd like instead is to get all the output as a string (`char *`).  The kind of API I'd like is:

```
/** Create a FILE object that will direct writes into an in-memory buffer. */
FILE *open_string_buffer(void);

/** Get the combined string contents of a FILE created with open_string_buffer
    (result will be allocated using malloc). */
char *get_string_buffer(FILE *buf);

/* Sample usage. */
FILE *buf;
buf = open_string_buffer();
do_some_stuff(buf);   /* do_some_stuff will use fprintf to write to buf */
char *str = get_string_buffer(buf);
fclose(buf);
free(str);
```

The **glibc** headers seem to indicate that a FILE can be set up with hook functions to perform the actual reading and writing.  In my case I think I want the write hook to append a copy of the string to a linked list, and for there to be a `get_string_buffer` function that figures out the total length of the list, allocates memory for it, and then copies each item into it in the correct place.

I'm aiming for something that can be passed to a function such as `do_some_stuff` without that function needing to know anything other than that it's got a `FILE *` it can write to.

Is there an existing implementation of something like this?  It seems like a useful and C-friendly thing to do -- assuming I'm right about the `FILE` extensibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If portability is not important for you, you can take a look on [fmemopen](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fmemopen) and [open_memstream](http://linux.die.net/man/3/open_memstream). They are GNU extensions, hence only available on glibc systems. Although it looks like they are part of POSIX.1-2008 ([fmemopen](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html) and [open_memstream](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open_memstream.html)).

Comment: open_memstream is exactly what I want.  I'm not sure if it's using the linked-list approach, but I won't be writing huge amounts to it so it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if it's possible to non-portably extend `FILE` objects, but if you are looking for something a little bit more POSIX friendly, you can use `pipe` and `fdopen`.

It's not exactly the same as having a `FILE*` that returns bytes from a buffer, but it certainly is a `FILE*` with programmatically determined contents.

```
int fd[2];
FILE *in_pipe;

if (pipe(fd))
{
   /* TODO: handle error */
}

in_pipe = fdopen(fd[0], "r");
if (!in_pipe)
{
   /* TODO: handle error */
}
```

From there you will want to write your buffer into `fd[1]` using `write()`.  Careful with this step, though, because `write()` may block if the pipe's buffer is full (i.e. someone needs to read the other end), and you might get `EINTR` if your process gets a signal while writing.  Also watch out for `SIGPIPE`, which happens when the other end closes the pipe.  Maybe for your use you might want to do the `write` of the buffer in a separate thread to avoid blocking and make sure you handle `SIGPIPE`.

Of course, this won't create a seekable `FILE*`...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand why you want to mess up with FILE *. Couldn't you simply write to a file and then load it in string?

```
 char *get_file_in_buf(char *filename) {
   char *buffer;
   ... get file size with fseek or fstat ...
   ... allocate buffer ...
   ... read buffer from file ...
   return buffer;
 }
```

If you only want to "write" formatted text into a string, another option could be to handle an extensible buffer using `snprintf()` (see the answers to this SO question for a suggestion on how to handle this: [Resuming [vf]?nprintf after reaching the limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1706587/resuming-vfnprintf-after-reaching-the-limit)).

If, instead, you want to create a type that can be passed transparently to any function taking a `FILE *` to make them act on string buffers, it's a much more complex matter ...

Comment: There are good reasons to want such a `FILE*`: There are many libraries that offer only `FILE*`-based I/O, and insist upon reading a file, when the data may already be available in memory. It's desirable, therefore, to be able to pass the memory buffer rather than write out to a file just for these libraries. Unfortunately, these libraries rarely, if ever, offer an alternative to their `FILE*`-dependent API.