# How to specify a variable expression list in a Pro*C query?

Tags: c, oracle, embedded-database, oracle-pro-c

I have a problem with a Pro*C query I'm trying to optimise.

To explain, our application searches for rows in a huge database. These rows exist in several languages and the old code selected a row for each language in an array. Now as these queries are the most time consuming part of our app, I wanted to make only one query which writes directly in an array.

The language codes are 2 letter ISO-639 codes (en for english, fr for french).

Old way (this is only a simplified code to show the intention)

```
struct ROW arr[MAX_LAN];
struct ROW_IND arr_ind[MAX_LAN];
uint_t LanIdx;
for(LanIdx=0; LanIdx<MAX_LAN; LanIdx++) {
  EXEC SQL SELECT *  /* Don't look at the *, it's for obfuscation only */
      INTO :arr[LanIdx]:arr_ind[LanIdx]
      FROM table WHERE id=:uniqid AND language=:LanCode[LanIdx];
}
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
EXEC SQL SELECT *  /* Don't look at the *, it's for obfuscation only */
    INTO :arr:arr_ind
    FROM table WHERE id=:uniqid AND language IN (:LanCodes);
```

but do not know how I should define LanCodes.

It works with a constant (compile time) list like this

```
EXEC SQL SELECT *  /* Don't look at the *, it's for obfuscation only */
    INTO :arr:arr_ind
    FROM table WHERE id=:uniqid AND language IN ('en','fr','de');
```

but this is not useful, as the languages may vary from case to case.

If I write something like

```
char LanCodes[MAX_LANS*5];
sprintf(LanCodes, "%s", LanCode[LanIdx]);

EXEC SQL SELECT *  /* Don't look at the *, it's for obfuscation only */
    INTO :arr:arr_ind
    FROM table WHERE id=:uniqid AND language IN (:LanCodes);
```

it works only if there is 1 language code in the string.

So my question is, does anybody know how to make this work? The Oracle documentation is so big, I don't know where to look at. I tried different ways, but none worked.

**EDIT**
Ok, I found a solution that works. It's not elegant, it's not advanced but it works well. I put a list of OR clauses in my query and it returns what I need in the form that I need.

```
EXEC SQL SELECT *  /* Don't look at the *, it's for obfuscation only */
    INTO :arr:arr_ind
    FROM table WHERE id=:uniqid AND (
                language=:v1[ 0] OR
                language=:v1[ 1] OR
                language=:v1[ 2] OR
                language=:v1[ 3] OR
                language=:v1[ 4] OR
                language=:v1[ 5] OR
                language=:v1[ 6] OR
                language=:v1[ 7] OR
                language=:v1[ 8] OR
                language=:v1[ 9] OR
                language=:v1[10] OR
                language=:v1[11] OR
                language=:v1[12] OR
                language=:v1[13] OR
                language=:v1[14] OR
                language=:v1[15] OR
                language=:v1[16] OR
                language=:v1[17] OR
                language=:v1[18] OR
                language=:v1[19] OR
                language=:v1[20] OR
                language=:v1[21] OR
                language=:v1[22] OR
                language=:v1[23] OR
                language=:v1[24] OR
                language=:v1[25] OR
                language=:v1[26] OR
                language=:v1[27] OR
                language=:v1[28] OR
                language=:v1[29] OR
                language=:v1[30]);
```

It's faster when there is more than 2 languages, so I call this variant or the old one depending on number of languages to fetch.

Comment: Check out this question / answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745811/using-c-convert-a-dynamically-allocated-int-array-to-a-comma-separated-string-as )

Comment: You're still going to have to parse the IN clause at runtime using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this [AskTom article](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:146012348066) can help you.

Comment: Thank you, that looks like something to try out. Follow up on friday to see if it works (and if it is faster).

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without [Oracle Dynamic SQL](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14407/pc_13dyn.htm#i13162). You will have to build your IN clause at runtime and EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. At least you can use Method 1, based on your queries.

Comment: I'm not sure, with method 3 it would boil down to the same problem. If I make a OPEN C USING :LanCodes will it work? One thing I forgot to mention, is that I cannot build a dynamic statement in a string with changing language codes as this would explode the statement cache of the database.

Comment: Then I think you need to build a temp table and populate it with your IN values, and join to that.

Comment: Thank you, but that's even worse (it would take months to get something like that through to our DBAs, we're here in an administration, this would involve a lot of paperwork).
I think I will have to live with our current solution (which is not bad btw.). It was only to gain a little on the selects which are the dominant part of the application.

Comment: Plus, you lose something by having to insert the values in the temp table as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a table before composed of an ID and a set of rows where the rows are the permutation of the possible values in the "in" list.  Then I join to the table based on the
ID and it gives me the results I need.

```
create table permute (
  id number,
  lang char(2)
);
create index permute_p1 on permute ( lang, id );
insert into permute ( id, lang ) values ( 1, 'en' );
insert into permute ( id, lang ) values ( 2, 'en' );
insert into permute ( id, lang ) values ( 2, 'fr' );
...
```

All you have to do then is pick the correct "ID" value 2, 3, 4 ... and put that into the
join.

Comment: That won't be possible. It's for the EU, so we have to handle 23 official languages (+2 others in the near future), so we have 23! possibilities, that's 25x10^7, the table would be almost as big (or even bigger) as our main database.

Answer (score 0):

...
Main String:= 'Select * FROM table WHERE id=:uniqid AND language IN'; -- can split into two to accomadate :uniqd
...
Select Language_code into v_string 
from x_table;
loop
 Copy & Concat v_string to LanCode_String and with ' ', ;
end loop;
..
Concat Lancode to Main String.
..
Prepare and execute the Main String.

Comment: Yes, that's basically what DCookie suggested. The problem with that approach is that it has a bad influence on the statement cache of Oracle. Overflowing that cache degrades the performance globally (had the effect some time ago for something else). My question was only to save a little on round-trips.