# Heterogeneous data types in multiple dynamic values in a Pro *C query IN clause

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-pro-c, embedded-sql

This is related to the following discussion

[Multiple dynamic values in a Pro *C query IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22917859/multiple-dynamic-values-in-a-pro-c-query-in-clause)

My question is: What determines the value of L[..], is it the length of data defined in Oracle Table Description as Varchar(100) or size of the destination buffer of character array say defined of size 50 i.e. char xx[50]; then should L[..] be 100 or 50? And data type T[..] should be 1?
If I use data type T[..] as 6, then will the value of L[..] change?
What about datatypes in destination (our own data structures where we fetch the results) are declared as int, long, short whereas Oracle side datatype is NUMBER(10), what we should use as T[..]? 3? and length L[..] as sizeof(int)?

Please help me with a detailed note on usage of L and T variables related to the V variable.