# FILE* that goes nowhere

Tags: c++, c, file-io, bitbucket

Is there a way to get a C stream object (a `FILE*` object) that points at nothing?

I know `fopen("/dev/null","w");` would work but I'm wondering if there is a better way.

Preferably that bit buckets the data at a higher level than the posix layer and that is also more portable.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? There's probably a better way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have some logging in place that goes to `stderr` and I want to be able to turn it off with a flag. I'd really rather not have to do more to it than change the variable that gets passed to `fprintf`.

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741191/creating-a-file-stream-that-results-in-a-string.  The stdio implementation always seems to support such things, but the API doesn't provide a nice way to use it.

Answer (score 10):

No: `/dev/null` on Unix and `NUL:` on Windows (in the absence of Cygwin or equivalent) is the best way to do it.

(*The original version of the question mentioned `fopen("/dev/null","o");` but has since been fixed.*)
Oh, and the `"o"` flag to `fopen()` is non-portable.  The portable forms include flag characters `r`, `w`, `a`, `b`, `+` in various combinations.

Comment: "O"K, I knew I should have looked that up. I was working from memory.

Comment: @Anacrolix: I've no idea what 'o' does; it isn't portable and doesn't apply to the systems I have available...I think it was intended to be a variant on 'w'.

Comment: why the  `:` - on Windows, the null device is called `NUL` (see eg http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365247%28VS.85%29.aspx#naming_conventions for a complete list of reserved file names)

Comment: @Christoph: because I was under the illusion that the colon was either necessary or desirable to indicate that it was the device that you wanted. If it fails with the colon, it is a fixable fault in my answer; if the colon is merely unnecessary, then put it down to a bad habit picked up sometime in the previous millennium.  I am not completely alone in my understanding - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS#Reserved_device_names.

Answer (score 6):

> I have some logging in place that goes to stderr and I want to be able to turn it off with a flag. I'd really rather not have to do more to it than change the variable that gets passed to fprintf

a) Wrapper function

```
logging = TRUE;
void debugprint(...)
{
    if (logging)   
    {
        fprintf(stderr, ...);
    }
}
```

b) I think fprintf will return if you give it a null pointer. Can't remember -- give it a try. Then all you have to do is change the pointer :)

Comment: a) for that much work I could switch to a real logging system. b) that's worth looking into +1

Comment: b)a quick look around seems to indicate that `fprintf(NULL,"");` will fail.

Comment: All you would have to do is add one function and search + replace for all instances for fprintf(stderr).

Comment: I thought it might. C std lib tends not to check it's parameters.

Comment: Passing a null file pointer to fprintf() leads to undefined behaviour, and usually to a crash and core dump on Unix-like systems.