# String Stream in C

Tags: c, string, stream, stdio

```
print2fp(const void *buffer, size_t size, FILE *stream) {

 if(fwrite(buffer, 1, size, stream) != size)
  return -1;

 return 0;
}
```

How to write the data into string stream instead of File stream?

Comment: **String Streams** <br>
http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/String-Streams.html

Comment: Similar to my earlier question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741191/creating-a-file-stream-that-results-in-a-string

Comment: Since you don't have the POSIX 2008 string streams functions, you are probably out of luck - unless you can find a library that simulates them well enough for your purposes.

Answer (score 13):

There is a very neat function in the posix 2008 standard: [open_memstream](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open_memstream.html)(). You use it like this:

```
char* buffer = NULL;
size_t bufferSize = 0;
FILE* myStream = open_memstream(&buffer, &bufferSize);

fprintf(myStream, "You can output anything to myStream, just as you can with stdout.\n");
myComplexPrintFunction(myStream);    //Append something of completely unknown size.

fclose(myStream);    //This will set buffer and bufferSize.
printf("I can do anything with the resulting string now. It is: \"%s\"\n", buffer);
free(buffer);
```

Comment: Is there a good alternative to `open_memstream`?  A number of platforms (solaris among them) don't provide this [yet].

Comment: @BrianVandenberg The closest would be `asprintf()`, which is also not provided by all platforms. All other alternatives either have severe security problems because they can overrun the supplied buffer (`sprintf()` and `fmemopen()`), or force you to run the string generation twice to avoid failing when your preallocated buffer is too small (`snprintf()`). Only `asprintf()` and `open_memstream()` deliver safe single pass semantics. However, if `asprintf()` would work for you, you can easily implement your own version via two passes of  `vsprintf()`.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I'm porting a library I'm not a maintainer for to Solaris that uses `open_memstream` a fair amount and I was hoping to find a way to provide a custom version to avoid changing their code.  I may have to use library interposition with a custom `write()/close()` (calling the libc versions of course).

Comment: @cmaster @BrianVandenberg Regarding `fmemopen`, it does not overflow the buffer. This is explicitly stated in the manpage (`Attempts to write more than size bytes ... result in an error`), and also in Open Group spec (`This interface prevents overflow.`). There was a bug on this, fixed in June 2015.

Comment: @Fuujuhi Ah, thanks for pointing that out. That puts `fmemopen()` in the same class as `snprintf()`: Overrun-safe, but unterminated partial output in case of insufficient buffer space. Looks like you absolutely must check all error codes from the writing calls **and** the `fclose()` call to even recognize this condition safely.

Answer (score 4):

Use `sprintf`: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/

Here's an example from the reference:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  char buffer [50];
  int n, a=5, b=3;
  n = sprintf(buffer, "%d plus %d is %d", a, b, a+b);
  printf("[%s] is a string %d chars long\n", buffer, n);
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
[5 plus 3 is 8] is a string 13 chars long
```

Update based on recommendations in comments:

Use `snprintf` as it is more secure (it prevents buffer overflow attacks) and is more portable.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
  int sizeOfBuffer = 50;
  char buffer[sizeOfBuffer];
  int n, a = 5, b = 3;
  n = snprintf(buffer, sizeOfBuffer, "%d plus %d is %d", a, b, a+b);
  printf ("[%s] is a string %d chars long\n", buffer, n);
  return 0;
}
```

Notice that `snprintf`'s second argument is actually the max allowed size to use, so you can put it to a lower value than `sizeOfBuffer`, however for your case it would be unnecessary. `snprintf` only writes `sizeOfBuffer-1` chars and uses the last byte for the termination character.

Here is a link to the `snprintf` documentation: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/

Comment: Don't use sprintf(), virtually any use of sprintf() will explode some time. Use asprintf() instead, it will malloc a buffer of the required length for you.

Comment: Or `snprintf` in portable code. Also, please don't link to cplusplus.com, that website is full of errors. cppreference.com is better.

Comment: Also, sprintf and vsprintf have security concerns. http://www.codecogs.com/library/computing/c/stdio.h/printf.php?alias=snprintf  
**"** The sprintf and vsprintf functions are easily misused in a manner which enables malicious users to  arbitrarily change a running program's functionality through a buffer overflow attack. Because sprintf and vsprintf assume an infinitely long string, callers must be careful not to overflow the  actual space; this is often hard to assure. For safety, programmers should use the snprintf interface instead. **"**

Comment: Its too bad I didn't react to larsmans comment 2 years ago, but thanks to mike I saw them now.
Thanks for pointing out the flaw of sprintf. It is ofcourse a good virtue to teach good manners.  
Usage of cplusplus.com vs cpprefference: It might be that cplusplus has some errors, and probably due to the examples that in several places might provide a good example on a specific reference, but uses problematic functions (like _sprintf_) along the example.  
Personally i find cplusplus.com a lot easiere to read, and in some applications it is more important to understand than be correct.

Comment: some compilers would expect a const infront of the line :
int sizeOfBuffer = 50;