# How to convert a file stream to string in C?

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I'm using a system function which writes the output information into a stream of file pointer.

```
func(FILE *__fp)
```

I need to use this information in my program rather than printing this out to a file. For that I thought of creating a `tmpfile()` and writing to it then reading back from it. But is there a better way to get this information?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481157/string-stream-in-c is probably relevant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are OS-specific solutions to writing to a memory buffer instead of a file, like for example the POSIX [`fmemopen`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fmemopen.html) or [`open_memstream`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open_memstream.html) (both which should be very useful considering your `linux` tag).

You can also change the internal buffer to your own with [`setvbuf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/setvbuf).

---

On an unrelated note: Symbols starting with a leading underscore and followed by another underscore (like for example your `__fp` argument) are *reserved*. Such symbols may only be used by "the implementation", i.e. the compiler and library.

Comment: Yes. The function I was referring to is malloc_info which is a malloc library function.